# Displaying BLOB images with PHP is resulting in random images being/not being displayed

Tags: php, mysql, blob

Have had a few websites where I am storing images as BLOBs. Recently my website is randomly displaying some, but not others.

The code works perfectly on my localhost, however when I upload to my server not all images are being displayed.

You can check my site (under development) here: http://claremark.ca/nobots/rr/products.php?item=lplast. It should be displafing images for all albums.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: The images are throwing a 500. What's your error log say? Add the error and relevant code to the question.

Comment: 500 errors are normally due to catestrophic PHP code errors. What changed recently? Did the hosting company change the PHP version for example

Comment: when you refresh the page different images load.  when i go directly to an image's src it is showing.  this might be related to a timeout. see if this link regarding fastcgi ini in your httpd.conf helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715426/how-do-you-increase-the-apache-fastcgi-timeout-on-mamp-mamp-pro/24976009#24976009

Comment: Thank to all who commented. 

It turned out that the amount of traffic on my host was causing too many php calls and was timing out.

I dumped the BLOB images to files and am now simply displaying them from there.