# FastCGI timeout error MAMP Pro 4

Tags: apache, mamp, fastcgi, mamp-pro

I looked into older questions

https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4661/fastcgi-error-when-accessing-a-local-development-site-using-mamp-pro/6573#6573?newreg=aa4ad11b453f4c7f93882ce478d837a3

[How do you increase the apache fastCGI timeout on MAMP / MAMP Pro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715426/how-do-you-increase-the-apache-fastcgi-timeout-on-mamp-mamp-pro/24976009#24976009)

but my configuration is quite differente because I'm using MAMP Pro 4 and I have multiple PHP versions running

I tried to edit MAMP/fcg-bin/phpx.x.x.fcgi and add -idle-timeout 3600, since it seems a little cleaner

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=200
exec /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.45/bin/php-cgi -c "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php5.4.45.ini" -idle-timeout 3600
```

and also

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=200
exec /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.30/bin/php-cgi -c "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php5.6.30.ini" -idle-timeout 3600
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect i still get the same error

FastCGI: comm with server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.30.fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)

and i also try to edit apache > httpd.conf

```
#MAMP_FastCgiServer_MAMP
FastCgiServer /Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.4.45.fcgi -idle-timeout 2400
FastCgiServer /Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.6.30.fcgi -idle-timeout 3600
```

in this case Apache would not start

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only way it seem to be possible is by checking Xdebug in PHP tab.
I did try that before, but did not seem to work on first attempt.
I then checked, save, quit and relaunch MAMP PRO and it worked.

Comment: It didn't worked for me. Still get 30 seconds even with -idle-timeout=300 on fcgi

Comment: do you have MAMP PRO 4? you only need to enable Xdebug in PHP tab, it is also the official response from support team

Comment: Worked for me, too. MAMP PRO 4.2.1

Comment: Worked for me in MAMP PRO 5.1.1

Comment: Indeed this solution enabling Xdebug works for most timeout issues on MAMP. increasing max_execution_time seemed to be inconsequential in my case (no last commit postion). As such, incase of timeout, you will be able to continue from last commit position on your DB.. Which is great.

Answer (score 6):

In Mamp pro usally this problem is for the setting: "Individual Php version for every Host (CGI  mode)" .. uncheck this and save.

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks like CGI Mode uses a different timeout. Although max_execution_time 300 is set in php.ini it is somehow ignored. How can I change the timeout in CGI Mode?

Comment: Yes! Thank you - 6 hours of research and this was the answer! MAMP > PHP > Mode > Module (instead of CGI)

Comment: This will force you to have identical PHP versions on all the hosts, it's a no go.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem (MAMP Pro 4.6). It turned out it was caused by a PHP script I had that was stuck in an infinite loop and timed out. However, restarting the servers in MAMP did nothing. It seemed to only fix itself after restarting the actual MAMP application as shown below.

Obviously, you need to fix the script that is timing out but to get MAMP going again without a restart or having to edit `httpd.conf`:

1. Stop the servers
2. Open up **Activity Monitor** and search for `php-cgi`
3. Force quit all occurrences of `php-cgi`
4. Start the servers

You should find it runs again without issue. If it does happen again, just repeat the four steps.

Comment: Thank you! 3 years later you solved the problem for me ;)